# Error: How to fix the digitalWrite() error?

Tags: c, arduino, embedded

This part of my code is highlighted in red when I execute it. I'm a beginner so please help me solve it. The error is in the line just after the else part of the code.

Tried googling for the same.

```
const int ledPin=13;//ledpin,flamepin and buzpin are not changed throughout the process
const int flamepin=A2;
const int buzpin=11;
const int thresold=200;// sets threshold value for flame sensor
int flamesensvalue=0;//initialize flamesensor reading
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(flamepin,INPUT);
  pinMode(buzpin,OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  flamesensvalue=analogRead(flamepin); // reads analog data from flame sensor
  if (flamesensvalue<=thresold)
  { // compares reading from flame sensor with the threshold value
    digitalWrite(ledpin,HIGH);   //turns on led and buzzer
    tone(buzpin,100);
    delay(1000); //stops program for 1 second
  } else
  {
    digitalWrite(ledpin,LOW);//turns led off led and buzzer
    noTune(buzpin);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show more of your code, try for a [mre]. You may assume that we have the same environment.

Comment: Look at the build logs, do you get build errors? What errors? Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and edit your question to improve it.

Comment: First of all there is no code after the `else part of the code`

Comment: Are you sure you have called the `setup()` function before the `loop()`?

Comment: @Yunnosch I got confused actually. Thank you.

Comment: @KenY-N The `setup` function is called automatically by the Arduino framework. It then calls `loop` in an infinite loop.

Comment: Just for an experiment, replace the `LOW` with `HIGH`. If that helps then the definition of `LOW` is missing or wrong.

Comment: Please also heed the advice to show us a [mcve]. We need to see what header files you include.

Comment: Hmm, judging by the answers "highlighted in red when I execute it" seems to mean here that the code is not actually executed; the compilation failed with an error.

Comment: @KenY-N You are right. But confusing "executing" with "compiling", or "building" or "pre-processing" or "linking" or "loading" is a very common mistake... Especially with IDEs which do all of that on one button...

Comment: Sorry people, especially the keen-eyed answerers. I think it is time to close this as a typo. Actually several typos....

Answer (score 4):

Even if your question is incomplete:

```
const int ledPin=13;


digitalWrite(ledpin,LOW);//turns led off led and buzzer
```

The "digitalWrite" Error could come from this difference. C and C++ are case sensitive.
`ledPin` and `ledpin` are different names.

Next time you should show the real error message, since the compiler will always tell exactly you  what is wrong.

Comment: Keen eye, enough of an upvote reason for me. Though I believe that if this is the answer, then the problem should have occurred BEFORE the else, not after.

Answer (score 3):

```
noTune(buzpin);
```

should be

```
noTone(buzpin);
```

There is no function called `noTune()` Arduino.

Comment: Also a keen eye. Seems I need new glasses.

Comment: @Yunnosch Haha! We don't need keen eye but we surely need compiler errors for this kind of question. :D

Comment: True, kiran Biradar. That is why [mre] has repeatedly been mentioned.